# service error 404 (Not Found)

Tags: mysql, angular, service

Hi developers i am trying to get data from my database to valid if the user exist in table or not then in the next coming stop i ll create a session for him , but when i try to test if the http request work or not i always get blocked buy this error while my REST API work fine

auth.service.ts

```
getetudiant(username, password) {
       return this.http.get('localhost/Admin/src/api/api.php?action=auth&username=' + username + '&password=' + password)
            .map(res => res.json());
}
```

controller :

```
recuperation(username, password) {
        this.authService.getetudiant(this.username, this.password)
            .subscribe((data: any) => {
                this.donnee = data;
                console.log(data);
            }, error => {
                console.log(error);
            });
    }
```

and this is the API

```
 $username=$_GET['username'];
    $password=$_GET['password'];


    $query="Select* from admin where id_admin='$username'and pass_admin='$password'";
    $result=$db->query($query);
    $response=[];
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0)
    {
        $response['status']='loggedin';
        $response['user']=$username;

    }else{
        $response['status']='error';
    }
    echo json_encode($response);
```

> GET 
>   http://localhost:4200/localhost/Admin/src/api/api.php?action=auth&username=charfedinne&password=amri
>   404 (Not Found)
>
> index-component.component.ts:29 Response {_body: "↵↵↵↵↵↵", status: 404,
>   ok: false, statusText: "Not Found", headers: Headers, …}

i ll be so grateful if any one can help

Comment: Looking at the URL `localhost/Admin/src/api/api.php` I would guess that you are using the wrong url to talk to the server. Where are the other API's that you call? Do they have the same URL?

Comment: Try changing the URL to `localhost/api/api.php` or `localhost/Admin/api/api.php`. Also check which port the website is running on

Comment: Agree with above comments and since it is a get request u can just type the path in the browser to see if it works.

Comment: thank you guys my url was missing "http://" <3 <3

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using wrong URL, check the URL by [postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) tools.
If your URL is corret then you will get the result of this.

1. check port
2. check API and action name

Reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_404